# How to get object like value:item:private from PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the array like this:

> }   ["items":"Jcart":private]=>   array(3) {
>       [0]=>
>       string(1) "3"
>       [1]=>
>       string(1) "2"
>       [2]=>
>       string(7) "ABC-123"   }

How to get the "items" values in a php variable?

///////

Te complete object is:

```
object(Jcart)#1 (8) {
  ["config"]=>
  array(12) {
    ["jcartPath"]=>
    string(6) "jcart/"
    ["checkoutPath"]=>
    string(12) "checkout.php"
    ["item"]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(10) "my-item-id"
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "my-item-name"
      ["price"]=>
      string(13) "my-item-price"
      ["qty"]=>
      string(11) "my-item-qty"
      ["url"]=>
      string(11) "my-item-url"
      ["add"]=>
      string(13) "my-add-button"
    }
    ["paypal"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(38) "seller_1282188508_biz@conceptlogic.com"
      ["https"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["sandbox"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["returnUrl"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["notifyUrl"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["currencyCode"]=>
    string(3) "USD"
    ["csrfToken"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["text"]=>
    array(14) {
      ["cartTitle"]=>
      string(13) "Shopping Cart"
      ["singleItem"]=>
      string(4) "Item"
      ["multipleItems"]=>
      string(5) "Items"
      ["subtotal"]=>
      string(8) "Subtotal"
      ["update"]=>
      string(6) "update"
      ["checkout"]=>
      string(8) "checkout"
      ["checkoutPaypal"]=>
      string(20) "Checkout with PayPal"
      ["removeLink"]=>
      string(6) "remove"
      ["emptyButton"]=>
      string(5) "empty"
      ["emptyMessage"]=>
      string(19) "Your cart is empty!"
      ["itemAdded"]=>
      string(11) "Item added!"
      ["priceError"]=>
      string(21) "Invalid price format!"
      ["quantityError"]=>
      string(38) "Item quantities must be whole numbers!"
      ["checkoutError"]=>
      string(34) "Your order could not be processed!"
    }
    ["button"]=>
    array(4) {
      ["checkout"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["paypal"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["update"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["empty"]=>
      string(0) ""
    }
    ["tooltip"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["decimalQtys"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["decimalPlaces"]=>
    int(1)
    ["priceFormat"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["decimals"]=>
      int(2)
      ["dec_point"]=>
      string(1) "."
      ["thousands_sep"]=>
      string(1) ","
    }
  }
  ["items":"Jcart":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["names":"Jcart":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [3]=>
    string(12) "Hockey Stick"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "Baseball Mitt"
  }
  ["prices":"Jcart":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [3]=>
    string(5) "33.25"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "19.50"
  }
  ["qtys":"Jcart":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [3]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
  ["urls":"Jcart":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [3]=>
    string(15) "http://bing.com"
    [2]=>
    string(16) "http://yahoo.com"
  }
  ["subtotal":"Jcart":private]=>
  float(423.25)
  ["itemCount":"Jcart":private]=>
  int(21)
}
```

I just need the values in ["items":"Jcart":private]

Comment: $var = $array["items":"Jcart":private][0];  ?

Comment: Unserialize the object, and use it's existing pethods to retrieve the data

Comment: I will trying your solutions @MarkBaker

Answer (score 1):

I assume you got this by casting an *object* to an array. If that's the case, you shouldn't be doing that! The property is private because you're not supposed to access it directly because it's not a public API. The object *should* have a public method which you're supposed to call instead, that's the public API. Something like `$foo->getItems()` or such. Read the documentation and/or source code.

Comment: i've been edited the question, can you see and helpe me. Thanks

Comment: Again: read the documentation. You're not supposed to access that property directly, the class ought to have other means of letting you get the information you need out of it.